# syntax error, unexpected 'false' (T_STRING)?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

when I write this

```
<?php 

   bbp_list_forums(array ( 'show_topic_count' ) false, ( 'show_reply_count' ); false ( 'separator' ); ( '' );); 

?>
```

In an IDE I get

```
syntax error, unexpected 'false' (T_STRING) ?
```

Comment: Expected error, because that code is a mess and I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So do you really think that's correct syntax? Doesn't even look correct to a bare eye, let alone to an IDE

Comment: Maybe this is the documentation you need? http://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_list_forums/

Comment: Your semicolons in the array() are just dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is a part of bbpress I think the following link could prove to be helpful.

http://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_list_forums/

Answer (score 0):

Are you mad?

How dare You to put semicolon(;) with arrguments.

**I thik It should be:**

bbp_list_forums(array ( 'show_topic_count' ), false,( 'show_reply_count' ), ( 'separator' ), ( '' ));

Comment: maybe i should have mentioned i have never written any code other than html before and i was just guessing based on the rest of the document? thank you, either way :)